# Is there a Kohana equivalent for the native mysql_free_result?

Tags: kohana

Like the question says

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply unset() the result object.
The result object will then call `mysql_free_result`()

**e.g.**

```
// $result now holds a Datbase_Result object
$result = Database::instance()->query('SELECT * FROM table');

// To free the result, simply destroy the variable through means of unset()
unset($result);

// Result memory has now been freed
```